# Need advice on table relations

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a table `Users`:

```
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordSalt] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Comments] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastLoginDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastLoginIp] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [IsActivated] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsLockedOut] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LastLockedOutDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastLockedOutReason] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NewPasswordKey] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [NewPasswordRequested] [datetime] NULL,
    [NewEmail] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [NewEmailKey] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [NewEmailRequested] [datetime] NULL
```

This table has **1 to 1 relation** to `Profiles`:

```
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Sex] [bit] NULL,
    [BirthDay] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [MartialStatus] [int] NULL
```

I need to connect `user` to the all other tables in database so is it better to:
1) Make relations from `Users` - to other tables?
2) Make relations from `Profiles` - to other tables?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"? Are you talking about building a query to pull information from all tables that contain a [UserID] column or do you mean setting up foreign keys from the other tables?

Comment: Setting up foreign keys in another tables. Making normal relations between tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the table [Users] contains the Identity value and is therefore where the [UserID] value originates, I would create all the foreign keys back to it. From a performance standpoint, assuming you have your clustered index on both tables set on the [UserID] column there should be very little performance impact.

Technically I suppose the [Users] table could contain more data per row and therefore the index could span more pages and you could have milliseconds difference in lookups, but I think it makes more sense to relate it back to the table that created the [UserID] and is similarly named. That said, you can really do either.

Answer (score 0):

If the PK of `Profiles` is a FK to `Users`, I would maintain consistency and use `Users` as the parent table in other relationships across the database.

However, if it is a true one-to-one and not a one-to-zero or one relationship, it doesn't matter.

Another consideration is how the data in this database is accessed by any applications. Do the applications use an OR/M like Entity Framework which is aware of FK relationships? If so, consider using whichever table has columns which will most commonly be accessed by queries based on the child tables. For example, an application might display `Profiles.LastName` and `Profiles.FirstName` all over the place and very rarely read anything from the `Users` table. In this situation, you will save your database some I/O and save your developers some keystrokes by building relationships off the `Profiles` table.